# Voice Recorder like whatsapp in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, chat, message

I am working on a Ruby on Rails Application. There is a chat feature user can send real time messaging to each other, implemented using action cable.

Now client wants me to integrate the voice recorder like whatsapp.

Voice will record and then should send to the other user. Other user can play that file.

I got a sample in JS https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Is there any idea how can I do this in Rails? I am not even getting any reference to send the audio files in RAILS?

Comment: try this https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js

Comment: recording voice depends entirely on the client side. you can use something like Webrtc to record it and through ajax call send it to the backend(Rails) for further processing. https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC